# Docker compose file global restart policy

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Can I define a global restart policy on all the containers inside of a single docker-compose file instead of adding it individually in each service?

Comment: There is no such feature available. The syntax reference for the compose file is [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/), which should answer all questions of this sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out by @larsks, there is no such feature yet. But it is possible (since version `3.4`) to define common properties using `x-` keys and avoid repetition using YAML merge syntax:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
x-common-options:
  &common-options
  restart: always
  logging:
    options:
      max-size: '12m'
      max-file: '5'
    driver: json-file

services:
  service_one:
    << : *common-options
    image: image1
```

The above is the same as this:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  service_one:
    image: image1
    restart: always
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: '12m'
        max-file: '5'
      driver: json-file
```